# Please make the buttons line up on the CoC

Tags: feature-request, code-of-conduct

Just a small design request; please make the two buttons line up vertically:

[image]

Comment: The obvious solution here is to add some [annoying and superfluous text to the second box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNrv8.png)

Comment: @Shog9 or simply a `<br>`

Comment: I had to read your question three times (and look at the screenshot three times) before I realized you'd actually meant to say *make the two buttons line up* ***vertically***. It shouldn't have taken me so long to realize it was a simple typo. ;)

Comment: is it just me or text proposed by @Shog9 makes more sense than the rest of CoC? "Skibbidy do-da sha-ba-bam-boom!"

Comment: Yes, that's just you.